# C++ throws an unknown exception type, but only in production build

Tags: c++, pointers, node-gyp, dynamic-cast

I'm pretty new to C++ and have been working on a small project, and I've run into a bit of stumbling block. I have a map of pointers, and I need to be able to cast the stored pointers to the appropriate subclass pointers. Here's the snippet causing the issues:

```
std::map<int, noise::module::Module *> moduleInstance;

// ...

// This is a valid id set earlier
std::cout << id << std::endl;

// This is the same address as an instance of noise::module::Constant 
// created earlier
std::cout << moduleInstance[id] << std::endl;

// This works, and is a value set by the subclass, so it exists and is 
// being instantiated correctly.
std::cout << moduleInstance[id]->sourceModuleCount << std::endl;

noise::module::Constant *constantModule;

try {
    constantModule = dynamic_cast<noise::module::Constant *>(moduleInstance[id]);
} catch(const std::runtime_error& re) {
    std::cout << "Runtime error: " << re.what() << std::endl;
} catch (const std::exception& ex) {
    std::cout << "Error occurred: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
} catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Unknown error" << std::endl;
}

// This is a random address unless built with --debug
std::cout << constantModule << std::endl;

// This also works fine with --debug
if (constantModule == nullptr)
{
    std::string err = "Module id '" + std::to_string(id) + "' is not an instance of ConstantModule.";
    Nan::ThrowReferenceError(Nan::New(err).ToLocalChecked());
    return;
}
```

Based on what I've read, if there's an issue this should fail by setting the pointer to the null pointer. However, when I run a production build it prints `Unknown error`, and is not recoverable. If I build with the `--debug` flag, it works (apparently) flawlessly.

How would I go about debugging this? So far I haven't even been able to tell *what* error is being thrown, let alone *why*. Even just being able to find the name of the error would be a useful starting place.

---

Edit to add a (non-)working example:

main.cc

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <nan.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class SuperClass
{
  public:
    SuperClass()
    {
    }

    virtual int virtualMethod() = 0;
};

class SubClassA : public SuperClass
{
  public:
    SubClassA() : SuperClass()
    {
    }

    int virtualMethod()
    {
        return 3;
    }
};

class SubClassB : public SuperClass
{
  public:
    SubClassB() : SuperClass()
    {
    }

    int virtualMethod()
    {
        return 4;
    }
};

std::map<int, SuperClass *> instanceMap;

void Run(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &info)
{
    SubClassA *subClassAInstance = new SubClassA();
    SubClassB *subClassBInstance = new SubClassB();

    instanceMap[0] = subClassAInstance;
    instanceMap[1] = subClassBInstance;

    SubClassB *subClassPtr;

    try {
        subClassPtr = dynamic_cast<SubClassB *>(instanceMap[1]);
    } catch (...) {
        cout << "Unknown error" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (subClassPtr == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Not an instance of SubClassB" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        assert(subClassPtr->virtualMethod() == 4);
        cout << "Addon done" << endl;
    }
}

void Init(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports)
{
    exports->Set(
        Nan::New("run").ToLocalChecked(),
        Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(Run)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

binding.gyp

```
{
    "targets": [
        {
            "target_name": "addon",
            "sources": [
                "./main.cc"
            ],
            "include_dirs": [
                "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

main.js

```
const addon = require('bindings')('addon');

addon.run();

console.log('JS Done');
```

Setup

```
npm init -y
npm i --save bindings nan
node-gyp configure
```

Run

```
node-gyp rebuild && node ./main
```

Comment: Debug builds often make some changes to help you find bugs, zeroing data to help you spot null pointers and stuff like that. Sometimes it backfires and hides a bug like an unterminated string .

Comment: How to debug this.... This is going to sound like a dodge, but make a [mcve]. If you can reduce the program to the bug, only the bug, and nothing but the bug, more often than not the bug becomes obvious. You still may not know how to fix it, but at least you know exactly what it is and can ask about it directly. Also worth hitting your program with a tool like valgrind to see if it can spot any ugliness for you.

Comment: Presence of `Nan::ThrowReferenceError` makes me think that this is nodejs addon. How do you call this code? Do you have multiple threads or global variables by any chance?

Comment: Is there any chance that RTTI is turned off in release mode?

Comment: @VTT Yup it's a node addon. I've added as minimal example as I could think of, and it's behaving the same.

Comment: @grinde if you don't catch it, does it print anything to console?

Comment: @Valentin It doesn't. The program simply halts.

Comment: @user4581301 Added an example as you suggested, and I was able to build a portion of it with g++. Unfortunately when I added the nodejs bindings back in so I could compile it with node-gyp I ran into the same problem. At this point if I had to guess I'd say it was something with node-gyp's build config. I've tried several different configuration overrides to enable RTTI (as MarkRansom suggested), but I'm unsure if they're actually doing the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was noticed by Mark in the comments, RTTI was turned off in the node-gyp build environment. Additionally it seems that (on windows at least) you can't override that setting with your binding.gyp. The fix was to edit `C:\Users\<user>\.node-gyp\<version>\include\node\common.gypi` directly by setting `'RuntimeTypeInfo'` to `'true'` under `'target_defaults' -> 'configurations' -> 'Release' -> 'msvs_settings' -> 'VCCLCompilerTool'`.

This isn't a great solution, so I've refactored the code to be able to use `static_cast` instead by setting type property with a unique value for each subclass.

Comment: Glad you found it.